# Using AJAX to get response - but page is still refreshing

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am having issues with filling in a form and pressing submit to send my information to a database. The problem is that my page refreshes even though I am using AJAX to stay on the same page and receive a reply in "show_label".

I have tested to see if addCustomerFunc gets called by changing the show_label, and it does change! But still refreshes and I lose the message after it refreshes. I was hoping if someone could catch my mistake(s).

This is in my customer.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addCustomerFunc(add_LN,add_FN,add_PN,add_DOB)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("show_label").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("POST","addCustomer.php",true);
xmlhttp.send("add_LN="+add_LN+"&add_FN="+add_FN+"&add_PN="+add_PN+"&add_DOB="+add_DOB);
}
</script>

    <p>Add New Customer:</p>
    <div align="center">
      <table width="337" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td width="154"><p>Last Name:</p>
          <p>First Name:</p>
          <p>Phone Number:</p>
          <p>Date of Birth:</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
          <td width="167"><p align="center">
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="add_LN" id="add_LN" />
                <br/><br/>
                <input type="text" name="add_FN" id="add_FN" />
                <br /><br />
                <input type="text" name="add_PN" id="add_PN" />
                <br /><br />
                <input type="text" name="add_DOB" id="add_DOB" />
                <br /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="add_Customer" id="New_Customer_Form" value="Add Customer" onClick="addCustomerFunc(add_LN, add_FN, add_PN, add_DOB)"/>
            </form>
            <div id="show_label"/>
          </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
```

addCustomer.php

```
<?php
$username="****";
$password="****";
$database="****";

$lastName=$_POST['add_LN'];
$firstName=$_POST['add_FN'];
$phone=$_POST['add_PN'];
$dob=$_POST['add_DOB'];
//$membership==$_POST['membership'];

mysql_connect("******",$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");


$query = "INSERT INTO customer (last_name, first_name, phone_no, date_of_birth, membership) VALUES ('$lastName', '$firstName', '$phone', '$dob', 'T')";

if (mysql_query($query)){
    echo "Thanks";
} else 
{
    echo "Failed to insert customer into database";
}

mysql_close();
```

?>

Also, am I passing the variables correctly in addCustomerFunc?
Am I using "Post" correctly?

Thanks!

Edit: I am now having issues with passing the variables because it says:
Undefined index: add_LN in C:\Users\ej\Desktop\cpsc471\presentation\addCustomer.php 
It adds blanks to my database though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a form, you need to make sure that you capture the `submit` event before it is allowed to proceed and refresh the page.

This should do the trick.  (notice the `return false`)

```
<input type="submit" name="add_Customer" id="New_Customer_Form" value="Add Customer" onClick="addCustomerFunc(add_LN, add_FN, add_PN, add_DOB); return false;"/>
```

Comment: THANKS! :D it stays on the same pagee!!!!
... But now im having another issue:
Undefined index: add_LN in C:\Users\ej\Desktop\cpsc471\presentation\addCustomer.php 

Also, it adds blank elements to my database even though I filled in the field form.

Should I create a new question for this because if I mark your answer as correct people will ignore this after?

Comment: to remove that 'Undefined index' change the 'ERROR_REPORTING' if php.ini file

Comment: Undefined index is a warning; this in particular case, it means the last name field is empty. You can use the isset() function to check if the index exists before using it, or do like most people and ignore that error since it's quite minor (see ERROR_REPORTING or ERROR_LEVEL). Of course, if the last name is required, you need to have some data validation in there (i.e. check that the last name field isn't blank) before you put anything in the db.

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of your button from:

`submit` to `button`

That way you stay on 1 page and the refresh will be gone :-)

Answer (score 0):

why not to use jQuery `$.post()` or `$.get()`?

btw, use:

```
<input type="button" name="add_Customer" id="New_Customer_Form" value="Add Customer" onClick="addCustomerFunc(add_LN, add_FN, add_PN, add_DOB)"/>
```

instead of :

```
<input type="submit" name="add_Customer" id="New_Customer_Form" value="Add Customer" onClick="addCustomerFunc(add_LN, add_FN, add_PN, add_DOB)"/>
```